# Stand-alone MS VSTS TFS Access for Windows Server 2008 (NOT R2)?

Tags: tfs, version-control

Yes, I know server 2008 is ridiculously old; but it is a client machine we cannot do anything about. Got that out of the way.

The client has an application which we maintain, and the source code lives on that machine, which is also the only machine around with VB6 on it (did I mention this project is old?).

I would like to find a client for the VisualStudio.com TFS services which can run on Server 2008 (not R2). Is there such a beast?

I've tried

- Visual Studio Code
- Visual Studio Community
- TFS 2010 Power Tools
- 2017 Team Explorer standalone

Sadly, none of them are compatible.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio is a kind of client of VSTS. But to be compatible server 2008 system. You could only use versions under Visual Studio 2008/Team Explorer 2008 for source control.

When you install Visual Studio 2008/Team Explorer 2008 successfully, you could also use [TF Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands) to do version control for your project.